# htaccess not working when I use rewriterule /canonical/url to another with params ?title=some-title

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using a web hosting server that is receiving urls like:

```
https://www.domain.es/blog/name-of-article
```

The .htaccess is trying to transform those urls to the GET form:

```
https://www.domain-name.es/blog-art.php?title=name-of-article
```

To do it I have, between any others, these two rules in the .htaccess:

```
\# blog.php
RewriteRule ^(.*blog)$ https://www.my-domain.es/blog.php [NC,R=301]
\# blog_art.php`
RewriteRule ^(.*blog)\/(.+)$ https://www.my-domain.es/blog_art.php?titulo=$2 [NC,R=301]
```

The second one is NOT working, it only works on my PC when it is localhost, but NOT working when it is on the web hosting server.

Why?

I tried on my localhost environment and all was working. I expected those rules to work too on the web hosting server, but the second one did not.

Comment: Why are you trying to match `.*` _before_ the `blog` part, when the URL paths of your examples _start with_ `blog`? And why are you _capturing_ that part, which you don't even need to create the substitution URL? (That is not likely to be the cause of the problem, but already indicates that you are probably not approaching this with that much proper logic ...)

Comment: Your live server might have `MultiViews` enabled, which can often lead to problems if you have a partial overlap between the beginning of your URL path, and physically existing files on the server - so try and disable that, and see if it changes anything. (And use `R=302`, while you are still testing, that will prevent your browser form caching faulty redirects.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, CBroe

I solved this before reading your post with:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

...

```
# blog.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*blog$
RewriteRule .*blog$ https://localhost:33/blog.php [NC,R=302,L]

# blog_art.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*blog/(.+)$
RewriteRule .*blog/(.+)$ https://localhost:33/blog_art.php?titulo=$1 [NC,R=302,L]
```

...

You are right that I don´t need `.*` before blog$ nor I need to capture it. I did it without knowing very much and in the thought of "just in case".

I had to read documentation and do tests.

I found a very good htaccess test page that I strongly recommend:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

I found it at:

[Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Which I strongly recommend too even more.

You are right too to advise me to use R=302 instead in my tests.

And I could recommend too to have a look at the apache documentation about rewrite rule flags:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

So you were right in all.

Thank you very much.

It is fixed now.